# Programmatically creating a user in an Azure Virtual Machine from a webapp in the same resource group

Tags: azure, ftp, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

I have an MVC Web App running in Azure inside of a resource group where I am also running a Virtual Machine to host an FTP service.  When I create user accounts in the web app, I'd like the application to simultaneously create a user account in the Virtual Machine such that the new user can log in to the FTP server.  As far as I can tell, the VM isn't part of a domain and we're not using Active Directory for these users.  The VM runs Windows Server 2016 Datacenter.  I've found approaches for doing this with Active Directory, and for Linux VMs, but those won't get the job done here.  Can anyone point me in the right direction here?  Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: have you found some way to create local users from your app ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  Other features have taken priority, and this remains a manual process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finally came back as an action item.  My solution involved writing a windows service that runs inside the VM and polls a database table both the app and the VM have access to.  When the service sees that an account has been requested, it creates the account and stores encrypted credentials in the database. I'm reasonably certain that what I was trying to do originally is impossible for security reasons.